# combination of 'update by reference' & rolling join yields in opposite results than expected by roll condition

Tags: r, data.table

I need to join two data.tables and update the first by reference. data.table `A`  contains only one `Date` column of weekdays only; data.table `B` contains one `Date` column of (all) calendar dates covering the same time period as the first data.table and in addition a equity column. Both data.tables are keyed by `Date`.

Method one `A[B,Equity:=Equity,on="Date"]` works fine, as all dates in `A` are also in `B`; but

Method two `A[B,Equity:=Equity,roll=+Inf,on="Date"]` does not join `Friday` with `Fridays`, but `Friday` with the following `Sunday`, which would be only consistent with the roll condition `roll=-Inf` (NOCB) (in this case there should be an exact match as in method one above anyway)

Method two `A[B,Equity:=Equity,roll=-Inf,on="Date"]` results in the exact join

In the code below, data.table `A` = `trad.dt` and data.table `B` = `cal.dt`.

```
library(data.table)
start.date <- as.Date("1997-01-01")
end.date <- as.Date("1997-02-01")
cal.seq <- seq(start.date,end.date,"days")
weekdays.excl <- c("Saturday","Sunday")
trad.seq <- cal.seq[!weekdays(cal.seq) %in% weekdays.excl]
cal.dt <- data.table(Date=cal.seq,Equity=1:length(cal.seq),key="Date")
trad.dt <- data.table(Date=trad.seq,key="Date")
trad.dt.noroll <- copy(trad.dt)
trad.dt.roll <- copy(trad.dt)
trad.dt.noroll[cal.dt,Equity:=Equity,on="Date"]
trad.dt.roll[cal.dt,Equity:=Equity,roll=+Inf,on="Date"]
all.equal(trad.dt.noroll,trad.dt.roll)
trad.dt.comb <- trad.dt.noroll[trad.dt.roll,on="Date"][,roll.minus.noroll:=Equity-i.Equity][,Weekdays:=weekdays(Date)]
```

I would expect both joins, either with `roll` without, to yield in the same results; In addition, the rolling join's `roll` condition seems to yield in unexpected results.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1217

Comment: thank you! yes, it does, and I agree with you about the odd behaviour. the current behaviour in terms of update by reference on rolling joins is actually very dangerous!

Comment: Feel free to provide an answer for your own question. It has nice reproducible example, and could be useful for future readers.